# Adding User Favorites in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, favorites

I am working on a Rails application that allows users to search for and browse recipes, using the [Food2Fork API](http://food2fork.com/about/api).

Versions:
Rails 5.0.0.1, ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]

I have a User model, Recipe model, and Favorites model. I am trying to allow for users who are logged in to favorite recipes they find. To be clear, both search and browse work with the recipes, as well as the logging in/logging out with users, so I know it's not an issue with the users themselves or accessing the API.

When trying to implement this favoriting system, I am getting the following error when I open the view (code is at the bottom):

```
undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Recipe:Class
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password 

    has_many :favorites
    has_many :favorite_recipes, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Recipe'

end
```

Recipe model:

```
require 'httparty'

class Recipe
include HTTParty

#define API base URL and key for project
ENV['FOOD2FORK_API_KEY'] = 'api_key_here' # (this was edited so I don't make my key public)
base_uri 'http://food2fork.com/api'
default_params key: ENV['FOOD2FORK_API_KEY']
format :json

#search method
def self.for term        
    get('/search', query: { q: term }) ["recipes"]
end

#show method
def self.find term
    get('/get', query: { rId: term }) ["recipe"]
end

def self.browse term
    get('/browse', query: { q: term }) ["recipes"]#random number
end

end
```

Favorite model:

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
 end
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create 
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    redirect_to '/home' 
  else 
    redirect_to '/register' 
  end 
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :location, :fname, :lname)
  end

end
```

Recipe controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @search_term = params[:ingredient]
    @recipes = Recipe.for(@search_term)
  end

  def show
    @id_r = params[:id]
    @recipe = Recipe.find(@id_r)
  end

  def browse
    @rand_num = params[:random]
    @rand_recipes = Recipe.for(@rand_num)
  end

end
```

Favorite controller:

```
class FavoriteRecipesController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_recipe

  def create
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @recipe, user: current_user)
      redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe favorited'
    else
      redirect_to @recipe, alert: 'Something went wrong.'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Favorite.where(favorited_id: @recipe.rId, user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
    redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe unfavorited.'
  end

  private

  def set_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id] || params[:id])
  end
end
```

Database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161123033852) do

  create_table "favorite_recipes", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "favorites", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "favorited_type"
    t.integer  "favorited_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.index ["favorited_type", "favorited_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_favorited_type_and_favorited_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_favorites_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.decimal  "location",        precision: 10
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "favorites", "users"
end
```

And finally, the view, in recipes/show.html:

```
 <% this_recipe = @recipe %>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

  </div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-grey" style="text-align:center">
<h1><%= this_recipe["title"] %></strong></h1>
<% if (this_recipe.nil? or this_recipe == []) %>
<p> <h2><strong>Sorry</b>, that recipe doesn't exist.</h2></p>
<% else %>
<center><div class="recipebox" style="padding:20px;margin:10px; border:1px solid orange; background:white;width:75%">
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p><%= link_to(image_tag(this_recipe["image_url"], height: '400', width: '400'), this_recipe["source_url"])%><br/>
(<%= link_to("View Recipe Source", this_recipe["source_url"]) %>)</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>Ingredients:</h2>
<% ingredients = this_recipe["ingredients"] %>
 <% ingredients.each do |i| %>
 &#0149; <%= i %> <br/>
 <% end %>

<p>
<%- unless current_user.favorite_recipes.exists?(id: @recipe.rId) -%>
<%= link_to 'Add to favorites', favorite_recipes_path(recipe_id: @project), method: :post %>
<%- else -%>
<%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_recipe_path(@recipe), method: :delete %>
<%- end -%>

</div>


 <% end %>
</center>
</div>
</div>

    </div>
```

I am unsure if I am not associating the models correctly, I'm not passing the information correctly, or what exactly is causing this error. Thank you for any help with figuring this out.

**Edit**

Trace:

```
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:106:in `relation_class_for'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:100:in `create'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:47:in `reader'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:111:in `favorite_recipes'
app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_recipes_show_html_erb___356804060_113751160'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:158:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:348:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:156:in `render'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in `instrument'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
```

Log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Recipe:Class):
    29:  <% end %>
    30:
    31: <p>
    32: <%- unless current_user.favorite_recipes.exists?(id: @recipe.rId) -%>
    33: <%= link_to 'Add to favorites', favorite_recipes_path(recipe_id: @recipe), method: :post %>
    34: <%- else -%>
    35: <%= link_to 'Remove from favorites', favorite_recipe_path(@recipe), method: :delete %>

app/views/recipes/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_recipes_show_html_erb___356804060_113751160'
  Rendering C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (1241.0ms)
```

Comment: can you show the stack trace for the error?

Comment: Added trace as well as log if that could possibly help as well. @maxpleaner

Comment: It doesn't look like your Recipe class is really an ApplicationRecord model. Maybe that HTTParty stuff can be extracted into a separate class. Other than that I'm not sure.

Comment: From what I understand HTTParty is needed to be included directly within the Recipe class to consume the API, so I'm not sure how I could separate them. How would I go about extracting it into a separate class to test if that would work? @maxpleaner

Answer (score 0):

For basic use, this is done with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

If you want more information on the Favorite model than just the fact that a User favorited a Recipe, you can break it out into its own class.

(WARNING: typed from scratch, has not been tested...but the idea is there)

```
class Favorite
  belongs_to :user
  # has a recipe_id field that's linked to the id of Recipe on Food2Fork API

  def recipe
    #... code to get a recipe from id ...
  end
end

class User
  has_many :favorites

  def favorite!(recipe)
    self.favorites.create(:recipe_id => recipe.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the error I now have after making these changes: undefined method `has_many' for Recipe:Class @Hong

Comment: They were function signatures, not meant exactly for your use case, but I've tweaked it a bit to accommodate the fact that Recipe is an HTTParty class. The general idea here is `Favorites#belongs_to :user` and has a reference to the recipe's id somehow. And that's what you use to associate the two together.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](http://schmidt-happens.com/articles/2014/06/04/favoriting-system-in-rails.html) tutorial and got a favouriting system set up in my app with ease. You can use the following implemntaion and set it up in your app.

Comment: that is actually what I was following, I did everything in that tutorial step by step.